# can I use sharepoint 2010 powershell within batch file?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, batch-file

Can use batch files enclosed with power shell commands for administrate the sharepoint 2010 and its user profile,roles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are dedicated cmdlets to manage sharepoint 2010 : see [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/20/get-started-managing-sharepoint-2010-with-powershell-cmdlets.aspx)

However, if you want to use existing batch you can call them like this within powershell

```
PS>cmd /c "C:\temp\test.cmd param1 param2"
```

Comment: the command you gave ...not running... is this recognized command?

Comment: just type `cmd /c "c:\path\to\yourbatch.bat"`  in powershell console, this should work fine

Comment: ok..will try..Thanks. Is anywhere the power shell commands with bat file? so that i can directly use in my java aaplication ?

Comment: yes launch this command : `powershell.exe &"c:\path\to\batch.bat param1 param2"`

Comment: what should be param1 and param2 ? and what should i expect with this ? sorry to ask..power shell is totally new for me ..

Comment: this was just an example, in case your batch is waiting for parameters... this will launch powershell then call command interpreter to run your batch (with parameters if required), then it will close powershell. If you dont want powershell to exit add the `-noExit` flag to the line